# asp.net mvc url routing to /Folder/Folder/Setup.exe?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

can I use ASP.NET MVC URL like this witout redirect to it from Global.asax?:

```
http://test.com/product/versions/0.9/Setup.exe
```

is this case products is `Controller` and `/versions/0.9/Setup.exe just a /folder/folder/Setup.exe`

how it should be in my controller?
without action.. or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore routes for a specific extension: [Make routing ignore requests for a file extension](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx)

Something like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*setupfiles}", new {setupfiles=@"(.*/)?.exe(/.*)?"});
```